# Cleveref won't work with enotez

Tags: cleveref, enotez

I want to set endnotes in my document with `enotez`, and I want to reference them using `cleveref`. However, I always get this error:

> LaTeX Warning: cref  reference format for label type `' undefined

According to the `cleveref` manual, one can define formats for reference types with `\crefname{type}{singular}{plural}`, where `type`corresponds to a counter. I have defined a format for the counter `endnote`; this counter is defined in `enotez.sty`, and it is known to LaTeX, as shown in the last line of output from the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backref]{enotez}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true,pdftex]{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{endnote}{Endnote}{Endnotes}

\begin{document}
This is an endnote with a label\endnote{Labeled endnote}\label{labeled}

Have you seen \cref{labeled} yet?

The current endnote\endnote{Another endnote} is \theendnote.
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

So, although the counter exists it isn't recognized by `cleveref`. What could I do about it?

Comment: Did you try putting `\crefname{endnote}` and `\Crefname{endnote}` in a `cleveref.cfg` file?

Comment: @Bernard It shouldn't make a difference whether the definition of `crefname` is put into the preamble or in an external config file -- except that you keep your preamble clean and mean. I tried it out, though, with the result that it didn't change anything. Thanks nevertheless! :-)

Comment: This is very likely because `enotez` does not use `\refstepcounter`... So I guess this is a feature request: make `enotez` compatible with `cleveref`

Comment: @clemens Right you are! This is a feature request: please make `enotez` compatible with `cleveref`! :-)

Comment: @Andreas would you mind posting this as an issue on https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/enotez/issues then? Else it is quite possible that I will forget about it

Comment: @clemens I just posted it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is due to a coding mistake in the `enotez.sty` package and should be notified to the package author.  The counter is change using `\stepcounter` and manually modifies `\@currentlabel` instead of just using `\refstepcounter`.  You can override the faulty construction as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[backref]{enotez}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true,pdftex]{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{endnote}{Endnote}{Endnotes}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \enotez_endnote_mark:n #1
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
    \quark_if_no_value:nTF {#1}
      {
        \refstepcounter {endnote}
        % \show \theendnote
        % \cs_gset:cpx {@currentlabel} {\theendnote}
        \enotez_write_mark:xn
          { \int_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int }
          { \theendnote }
      }
      {
        \cs_gset:cpn {@currentlabel} {#1}
        % \cs_gset_eq:NN \theendnote \@currentlabel
        \enotez_write_mark:xn { \int_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int } {#1}
      }
    \bool_if:NT \l__enotez_disable_bool
      {
        \int_gdecr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
        \addtocounter {endnote} {-1}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


This is an endnote with a label\endnote{Labeled endnote}\label{labeled}

Have you seen \cref{labeled} yet?

The current endnote\endnote{Another endnote}\label{tt} is \theendnote.
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Note there is a second manual setting of `\@currentlabel` in the above code I have not corrected as it is not used in your use case.

Comment: this is due to the history of the package: originally `enotez` didn't use a counter

Comment: @AndrewSwann Wonderful, that works great! Thanks a lot!