# Hyperlinks to endnotes from enotez have unexpected targets

Tags: hyperref, enotez

When using `enotez`, one can assign labels to an endnote and refer to them. However, I have found that `hyperref` links to unexpected targets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[backref]{enotez}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{endnote}{endnote}{endnotes}

% This code by Andrew Swann (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395662)
% makes \cref recognize counter `endnote`
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \enotez_endnote_mark:n #1
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
    \quark_if_no_value:nTF {#1}
      {
        \refstepcounter {endnote}
        \enotez_write_mark:xn
          { \int_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int }
          { \theendnote }
      }
      {
        \cs_gset:cpn {@currentlabel} {#1}
        \enotez_write_mark:xn { \int_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int } {#1}
      }
    \bool_if:NT \l__enotez_disable_bool
      {
        \int_gdecr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
        \addtocounter {endnote} {-1}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


This is an endnote with a labeldefinition inside the note.\endnote{Label in endnote\label{labelin}}
This endnote refers to the one with the labeldefinition inside.\endnote{See \cref{labelin}}

This is an endnote with a label defined after the note.\endnote{Label after endnote}\label{labelafter}
This endnote refers to the one with a following labeldefinition.\endnote{See \cref{labelafter}}
\newpage

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image: Wrong references in notes 2 and 4]

As you can see in the picture, the link from endnote 2 to endnote 1 is obviously wrong. It seems that if the label is placed inside of `\endnote{}`, it will always point to the last endnote.

The link in endnote 4 seems to be correct on first sight. However, I expected the link would point directly to endnote 3  (on the second page, under "Notes"). Unfortunately, it points back to page 1, where the endnote has been set.

Is there any way I could link to the actual text of an endnote instead of the endnote definition?

Comment: A look into the relevant `.aux` file after the compilation shows that the labels defined at the end appear first in the `.aux` file, so this is main culprit

Comment: @ChristianHupfer So there is nothing I could do about it (except filing a bug against `enotez`) -- right?

Comment: In a nutshell: Yes ;-) It depends whether it is a feature or a bug

Answer (score 2):

Today the redefinition of `\enotez_endnote_mark:n` is not necessary any more but the problem stays: *labels always refer to the last counter that has been refstepped*. This happens when the mark is generated and not when it is repeated in the list of notes. So actually the targets are very expected.

`enotez` uses own `\hypertarget`s for creating the links to the list. They can be accessed and be used to create some kind of `\label`/`\ref` that creates links to the position in the list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setenotez{backref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_andreas_labels_prop

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn {Nx}

\NewDocumentCommand \endlabel {m} {
  \prop_put:Nnx \l_andreas_labels_prop
    {#1}
    { \int_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \endref {m} {
  endnote \nobreakspace
  \hyperlink
    { enz. \prop_item:Nn \l_andreas_labels_prop {#1} }
    {
      \prop_item:Nx \g__enotez_endnote_mark_prop
        { \prop_item:Nn \l_andreas_labels_prop {#1} }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This is an endnote with a label defined after the note.\endnote{Label after
  endnote.}\endlabel{labelafter} This endnote refers to the one with a
following label definition.\endnote{See \endref{labelafter}.}

\newpage

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

The main problem with the code above is that it uses the internal variables `\g__enotez_endnote_mark_prop` and `\g__enotez_endnote_id_int`. Both could probably be made public, I guess…

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `\prop_gput:Nnx` instead of `\prop_put:Nnx`? Because if you create, for example, the endnote and its label within a figure environment, you can't reference it in the normal text unless you use `\prop_gput:Nnx` in the command definition.